# Why are parenthesis sometimes required in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax, syntax-error, ruby-2.2

I recently ran into an oddity while looking at some Ruby code from the [Rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html).

Ruby lets you pass arguments like these examples:

```
redirect_to post_url(@post), alert: "Watch it, mister!"
redirect_to({ action: 'atom' }, alert: "Something serious happened")
```

But that second case looked odd to me. It seems like you should be able to pass it like so:

```
redirect_to { action: 'atom' }, alert: "Something serious happened"
```

And it would have the same meaning with or without parenthesis. But instead you get:

```
syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'
```

Referring to the colon after `action`. I'm not sure why it would be expecting `}` there, and why using parenthesis would change that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `{ ... }` has two meanings: hash literal and block.

Consider this:

```
%w(foo bar baz).select { |x| x[0] == "b" }
# => ["bar", "baz"]
```

Here, `{ ... }` is a block.

Now imagine that you are calling a method on the current object, so the explicit receiver is not needed:

```
select { |x| x[0]] == "b" }
```

Now imagine that you don't care about the parameter:

```
select { true }
```

Here, `{ true }` is still a block, not a hash. And so it is in your function call:

```
redirect_to { action: 'atom' }
```

is (mostly) equivalent to

```
redirect_to do
  action: 'atom'
end
```

and it is nonsense. However,

```
redirect_to({ action: atom' })
```

has an argument list, consisting of a hash.

Answer (score 4):

Curly braces serve double-duty in Ruby. They can delimit a hash, but they can also delimit a block. In this case, I believe your second example is getting parsed as:

```
redirect_to do
  action: 'atom' 
end, alert: "Something serious happened"
```

Therefore your `action: 'atom'`, which is not valid as an independent expression, gets parsed as such.

The parentheses serve to disambiguate the `{...}` as a hash.

Comment: Hey what's with the downvote? This answer is correct.